# Alternatives for "similar to other studies"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, editing

When you want to compare the results of a research to other studies, you can use

> **Similar to other studies**, the current study indicates that ...

What are other alternatives for **'Similar to other studies'**? I can only suggest one another that is **'Consistent with the results of other studies'**.

Comment: Inkeeping with?

Answer (score 1):

In [accordance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accordance) with...

(As) [per](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/per?show=0&t=1397133657)...

In [line](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20line) with... (definition 3DI)

[Akin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/akin) to...

As in/with...

Answer (score 0):

If the study leads to the same conclusion and uses comparable methodologies, you could say it **[replicates](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/replicate)** the earlier study.

> Repeat (a scientific experiment or trial) to obtain a consistent result:
>   *these findings have been replicated by Atwood and Jackson*

Answer (score 0):

[In concordance with the results of other studies ...](http://www.nature.com/jid/journal/v126/n8/full/5700292a.html)